# How To Get First Parent By Child ID With MySql Query Or php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have this table:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mike | 0 |
| 2 | jeff | 0 |
| 3 | bill | 2 |
| 4 | sara | 1 |
| 5 | sam | 4 |
| 6 | shai | 5 |

I want to find first parent name,id by send id OR parent_id :

For example:

If I Send 6 id(shai) I want To Show That The First Parent That Name Is mike(id:1) But My Query Only Shows Previous parent and When I send 6 As id It Only Show sam(id:5).
How Can I Find First Parent By SQL Query Or Php Code?

This Is My Code:

```
SELECT child.id, child.name, child.parent_id, parent.name as ParentName FROM test child JOIN test parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id WHERE child.id=6;
```

Comment: Please learn to format your posts after being member for over 5 years.

Comment: use recursive CTE - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Comment: this is for mysql v8, i have mysql v5.7 @ProGu

Comment: In 5.7 - create iterative stored procedure.

Comment: can you explain more with an example or solve my problem by example? @Akina

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), parent_id INT);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> (1,   'mike', 0),
> (2,   'jeff', 0),
> (3,   'bill', 2),
> (4,   'sara', 1),
> (5,   'sam',  4),
> (6,   'shai', 5);
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> | id | name | parent_id |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | mike | 0 |
> | 2 | jeff | 0 |
> | 3 | bill | 2 |
> | 4 | sara | 1 |
> | 5 | sam | 4 |
> | 6 | shai | 5 |

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION get_most_parent (id INT)
> RETURNS CHAR(255) 
> BEGIN
> DECLARE parent_name VARCHAR(255);
>     REPEAT
>         SELECT name, parent_id 
>         INTO parent_name, id
>         FROM test
>         WHERE test.id = id;
>     UNTIL NOT id END REPEAT;
> RETURN parent_name;
> END
> ```

> ```
> SELECT test.*, get_most_parent(id) TopParentName 
> FROM test
> WHERE id IN (3, 6);
> ```
>
> | id | name | parent_id | TopParentName |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | bill | 2 | jeff |
> | 6 | shai | 5 | mike |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f452d01755aa4942c200d5539e6b9e3f)*

PS. Apply this method only to single user or tiny users set - the function executes the whole iterative selection process for each output row separately and independently. And avoid cycles in your data!

Comment: thanks but when I run CREATE FUNCTION get_most_parent on phpmyadmin sql section that returns #1064 error

Comment: @AminArjmand Non-related problem. Either read help or create another question - about functions creation via phpmyadmin.

Comment: should add this to begin and end for work
```DELIMITER $$
END$$
DELIMITER ;```